# gcc линковщик выдаёт undefined reference to 'sin'

Tags: c, gcc

Компилирую следующий код:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

double f(double x) {
        return sin(x);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
        return 0;
}
```

Вылезает ошибка линковщика:

> /tmp/ccWto7Ot.o: In function `f': temp.c:(.text+0x13): undefined
>   reference to`sin' collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

Никак не могу понять где я накосячил. Перебрал весь код, приведённый пример является минимальным для воспроизведения ошибки. Компилирую без опций, т.е. просто

> gcc test.c

Comment: Добавьте библиотеку libm: `-lm`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Компилирую без опций, т.е. просто

```
$ gcc test.c
```

а надо как минимум подключить библиотеку `libm.so`, для чего следует указать опцию `-lm`:

```
$ gcc -lm test.c
```

или, например, так:

```
$ make test CFLAGS=-lm
```